# App icons/button how to create custom image or Buy them for an app?

Tags: iphone, swift, icons

I have created an iOS app which is basically an app to point towards different pages of a website for easy access for a school, It has clickable buttons created using UiCollectionview so i haveused some basic images for these buttons which when clicked takes you to a specific URl, but these images are quite generic and I want to know that is there a way I can create specific custom images forbuttons which have names like about me, vourses, community etc such that the buttton image represents accurately the function which will be performed, Is there a paid site or designer who can create it as per my requirements? Please help me out

Comment: Your question bit hard to understand.What you mean **clickable buttons created using UICollectionview**.I think you confused with a collectioViewCell. CollectionViewCell its not a UIButton.I believe you just trying to populate a collectionView with a specific set of images.let me know the shape and size of the image.I will help...

Comment: Yes I get i put my question in a confusing way ..I need icon images which would look good on most of the iphone and ipad screens. Is that possible

Comment: Icon sizes are unique for each iPhone /iPad devices.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html checkout the apple doc about icon size ratio for each device and you have to create a set of icons for each icons...

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for this Info. But is it possible or is there any app or service which can convert like 1 image into all the possible screen sizes? for Iphone 5 onwards and Ipad 2 onwards till latest. I have used App icon gear app from app store but couldnt get the desired results. I appreciate your help

Comment: Try Asset Catalog creator from AppStore